# Rails mail gem: pass argument into .html template for sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail), is it possible to pass an argument to .html (or html.erb) template for sending that template with, let's say, username in body?
Here is my send mail method:

```
  def send_confirm
recipient = Email.find_by_id(self.email_id).email
title = self.title
Mail.deliver do
  from ENV['USER_NAME']
  to recipient
  subject 'Reminder has been logged: '+title
  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/reminder_templates/confirm.html.erb")
  end
end
```

Is it possible to pass an argument to that html_part, so it will be included in body? For example, self.username. And to have embedded ruby code in confirm.html.erb file some like `<p> Hi <%= self.username% > </p>`
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the mail gem instead of [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)?

Comment: Why not? :D I am experimenting!